# No errors are shown, but nothing is displayed when I run my code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a programming exercise. The overall point is that when someone enters a team name it will display how many times that team won the world series. It pulls this information from a file that it reads. The issue is that when I run the code, no errors are displayed but it doesn't display anything when I run the code. My question is, what am I missing in my print function or main function? Why is nothing being displayed when my code is run? My code is below.

```
def team_from_file(file_name):
    readfile = open(file_name, 'r')
    team_list = []

    team = readfile.readline()

    while team != ' ':
        team_list.append(team)
        team = readfile.readline()

    return team_list

def times_won(user_team_name, list_of_winning_teams):
    winning_times = 0

    for current_win in range(len(list_of_winning_teams)):
        if list_of_winning_teams [current_win] == user_team_name:
             winning_times = winning_teams + 1

    return winning_teams

def print_times_won(winning_team_name, winning_times):
    print(winning_team_name, 'has won the World Series', winning_times)


def main():
    file_name = "WorldSeriesWinners.txt"
    win_team_list = team_from_file(file_name)   
    user_input = input('Please enter team name: ')
    winning_times = times_won(user_input, win_team_list)
    print_times_won( print_times_won, winning_times )

main()
```

Comment: Add `print("hello")` right before you call `main`. Does it print? If not, how are you running this code?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for your response, I'm assuming you mean outside of the functions, and just. Before I call main. It does print.